# Cannot add(any of) global git configurations in .gitconfig file

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-16.04

I recently tried to add a configuration for git as global configuration. For example `git config --global core-editor "vim"`. I got the error as given below.

`error: could not write config file /home/admin/.gitconfig: Operation not permitted`

Like wise I also tried to add `git config --global color.ui always`. For this also the above error is thrown in the terminal.

Please help me.

Comment: Check /home/admin directory permissions, also check permissions for .gitconfig if it exists

Comment: @MichaelO. I checked permissions also.

```-rw-rw-r--  1 admin admin    196 Jul 11 23:31 .gitconfig```

Comment: And what are permissions for .gitconfig? and who's the owner?

Comment: I tried to change the permission to root level. That also didn't work

Comment: Are you user `admin`? Check with command `id`. Is the filesystem mounted read-only or read-write?

Comment: Yes I am the user ``admin``

Comment: ``uid=1001(admin) gid=1001(admin) groups=1001(admin)``
This is the result of ``id`` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `immutable(i)` attribute has been set for that file. When this attribute is enabled, we cannot alter, rename or delete file. Try the below command.

```
sudo chattr -i .gitconfig
```

Please visit [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/file-directory-attributes-in-linux-using-chattr-lsattr-command/) link for more details.